# How to access variable in JavaScript by C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I've script like this for Calendar , this is Jquery Calendar

I want to acccess to 'starttime' and 'startdate' in

```
  title: "Event 1",
                url: "http://www.jqueryscript.net",
                start: {
                    date: 20151115,
                    time: "12.00"
                },
                end: {
                    date: 20151115,
                    time: "14.00"
                },
```

by C# . Can you help me ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to access Javascript variable in C# OR C# variable in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Access Javascript variable in C#, you have to do following things
1. Add two hidden variable in HTML form.
2. Set the variables values using javascript.
3. When you submit the form, you can access the those variables values in C#. It'll be same way how you access the textbox value or any other controls.
   You can also do the HTTP post using jauqery and access the variable values.